# Laravel relationships eager loading: Call to undefined function productListing()

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a chain of related models that I want to load up together at once using Eloquent's eager loading feature, as per https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#nested-eager-loading. In my own case, I am trying to do:

```
$order = Orders::where('id', $orderId)
          ->with([
              "users",
              "shippingInvoices" => [
                  "shippingInvoiceDetails" => [
                      "orderDetails" => "productListing",
                  ],
                  "vendor"]
          ])->get();
```

But I get the following error: Call to undefined function productListing().
In the Orders model definition file, Orders.php, I have:

```
public function users() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Users', 'user_id');
}
public function shippingInvoices() {
        return $this->hasMany(ShippingInvoice::class, "order_id");
    }
```

In ShippingInvoice.php, I have:

```
public function shippingInvoiceDetails(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ShippingInvoiceDetails::class, "invoice_id");
    }
```

In ShippingInvoiceDetails.php:

```
   public function orderDetails(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(OrderDetails::class);
    }
```

In OrderDetials.php:

```
    public function productListing() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\ProductListing', 'product_id');
    }
```

Comment: Just for case, does `["productListing"]` works set as array?

Comment: @Tpojka Yes, making it an array fixed the code. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You have to call it like bellow.

```
$order = Orders::where('id', $orderId)
          ->with([
              "users",
              "shippingInvoices",
              "shippingInvoices.shippingInvoiceDetails",
              "shippingInvoices.shippingInvoiceDetails.orderDetails",
       "shippingInvoices.shippingInvoiceDetails.orderDetails.productListing",
              "vendor"
          ])->get();
```

you can access the related model with dot (.)

Comment: you don't need the 2nd, 3rd, and 4th array elements ... `shippingInvoices.shippingInvoiceDetails.orderDetails.productListing` is loading all of them already, down that whole path

Comment: You are correct.